# HTML function not working with button

Tags: javascript, html

I have this small bit of HTML and JS and I cannot for the life of me get the function to work with the button. I have tried many things and changed different styles of creating buttons and text boxes but I cannot figure out how to fix it.
Here is the Code:

```
<div id="orderForm">
  <form name="orderingForm" action="form_action.asp">
  <p>Complete this form to order Bags
    <br>
    <br> How many of each bag do you want (3p/ea)</p>

  <p>Number of Blue bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="blueBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Number of Red bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="redBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Number of Yellow bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="yellowBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Number of Green bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="greenBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Enter Desired Text:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="textBags" value="Enter Your text here">
    <p>Minimum order 100 bags</p>

    <input type="button" value="Click to Order" onClick="Order()">
  </form>
</div>

<!--Script for the ordering system-->
<script>

  <!-- extra functions to check if input is an integer -->
  function isInt(n) {
    return n % 1 === 0;
  }

  function Order() {
    var amountB = document.orderingForm.blueBags.value;
    var amountR = document.orderingForm.redBags.value;
    var amountY = document.orderingForm.yellowBags.value;
    var amountG = document.orderingForm.greenBags.value;
    var text = document.orderingForm.textBags.value;
    var total = amountB + amountR + amountY + amountG;

    if (isInt(form1.blueBags.value) == true && isInt(form1.redBags.value) == true && isInt(form1.yellowBags.value) == true && isInt(form1.greenBags.value) == true) {
      if (total > 100) {
        var cost = (total * 0.03);
        //if (confirm("CONFIRM ORDER: /n blue bags: " + form1.blueBags.value + "/n red bags: " + form1.redBags.value + "/n yellow bags: " + form1.yellowBags.value + "/n green bags: " + form1.greenBags.value + "/n Desired Text: " + text)) {
          alert("Order Confirmed");
        } else {
         alert("Order Cancelled");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Minimum order is 100 bags.");
      }
    } else {
      alert("One or more of the forms doesn't contain a quantity for order.");
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/j7tuw793/

Comment: } is missing, just add it

Comment: what about for the commented stuff? meant to uncomment that before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Here you miss handled with '{}' and your form name is "orderingForm" not "form1"

try this:

```
 <html>
<body>
<div id="orderForm">
  <form name="orderingForm" action="form_action.asp">
  <p>Complete this form to order Bags
    <br>
    <br> How many of each bag do you want (3p/ea)</p>

  <p>Number of Blue bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="blueBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Number of Red bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="redBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Number of Yellow bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="yellowBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Number of Green bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="greenBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Enter Desired Text:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="textBags" value="Enter Your text here">
    <p>Minimum order 100 bags</p>

    <input type="button" value="Click to Order" onClick="Order()">
  </form>
</div>
</body>
<!--Script for the ordering system-->
<script>

  <!-- extra functions to check if input is an integer -->
  function isInt(n) {
    return n % 1 === 0;
  }

  function Order() {
console.log("hai")
    var amountB = document.orderingForm.blueBags.value;
    var amountR = document.orderingForm.redBags.value;
    var amountY = document.orderingForm.yellowBags.value;
    var amountG = document.orderingForm.greenBags.value;
    var text = document.orderingForm.textBags.value;
    var total = amountB + amountR + amountY + amountG;

    if (isInt(orderingForm.blueBags.value) == true && isInt(orderingForm.redBags.value) == true && isInt(orderingForm.yellowBags.value) == true && isInt(orderingForm.greenBags.value) == true) {
      if (total > 100) {
        var cost = (total * 0.03);

          alert("Order Confirmed");

      } else {
        alert("Minimum order is 100 bags.");
      }
    } else {
      alert("One or more of the forms doesn't contain a quantity for order.");
    }

}

</script>     
</html>
```

hope it will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

You used .. and missed }. Try this

```
<div id="orderForm">
  <form name="orderingForm" action="form_action.asp">
  <p>Complete this form to order Bags
    <br>
    <br> How many of each bag do you want (3p/ea)</p>

  <p>Number of Blue bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="blueBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Number of Red bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="redBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Number of Yellow bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="yellowBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Number of Green bags:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="greenBags" value=0>
  </p>
  <p>Enter Desired Text:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="textBags" value="Enter Your text here">
    <p>Minimum order 100 bags</p>

    <input type="button" value="Click to Order" onClick="Order()">
  </form>
</div>

<!--Script for the ordering system-->
<script>

  <!-- extra functions to check if input is an integer -->
  function isInt(n) {
    return n % 1 === 0;
  }

  function Order() {
    var amountB = document.orderingForm.blueBags.value;
    var amountR = document.orderingForm.redBags.value;
    var amountY = document.orderingForm.yellowBags.value;
    var amountG = document.orderingForm.greenBags.value;
    var text = document.orderingForm.textBags.value;
    var total = amountB + amountR + amountY + amountG;

    //if (isInt(form1.blueBags.value) == true && isInt(form1.redBags.value) == true && isInt(form1.yellowBags.value) == true && isInt(form1.greenBags.value) == true) {
      if (total > 100) {
      //  var cost = (total * 0.03);
        //if (confirm("CONFIRM ORDER: /n blue bags: " + form1.blueBags.value + "/n red bags: " + form1.redBags.value + "/n yellow bags: " + form1.yellowBags.value + "/n green bags: " + form1.greenBags.value + "/n Desired Text: " + text)) {
          alert("Order Confirmed");
      //  } else {
      //    alert("Order Cancelled");
      //  }
      } else {
        alert("Minimum order is 100 bags.");
      }
    //}else {
    //  alert("One or more of the forms doesn't contain a quantity for order.");
  //  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First-off, don't use HTML Comments between your `<script>` tags, as you have:

```
<!-- extra functions to check if input is an integer -->
```

And you have a syntax error at `..` should be `.` "single dot", as you have:

```
var text = document.orderingForm..textBags.value;
```

This should be something like this:

```
var text = document.orderingForm.textBags.value;
```

And finally, you didn't close your `Order() function` ending bracket.

Checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c5496q92/

Updated for Understanding Comments in HTML and JavaScript:

When you wants to add some Comments in HTML, you can use:

```
<!-- Your Comments -->
```

And if you are working in .js file or between `<script></script>` tags you should use:

```
/* For multi-line comments */

// For singular line comment
```

You can read about this more at:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/website-design-basics/comment-php-javascript-html-css-code

Comment: COuld you give me some guidance on the commented out code as I am still having issues with it when i introduce it. cheers

Comment: Please follow this working jsfiddle that I have created for you [link](http://jsfiddle.net/c5496q92/), your problem will be resolved. Moreover, Check my updates in the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line as follows:

```
var text = document.orderingForm.textBags.value;
```

and to add two values use `parseInt(value)` or `parseFloat(value)` as:

```
var r = parseInt(amountB) + parseInt(amountR);
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `.` from this line

```
var text = document.orderingForm..textBags.value;
```

write

```
var text = document.orderingForm.textBags.value;
```

and close the `}` end of your code